# PreferenceKey not working when embedded in HStack - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

**The following code is a simplified version of the issue.**

The `Dimensions` view takes any combination of views and shows the width & height of all the views combined using PreferenceKeys.

As seen in Example 1: When constructing all the views inside `Dimensions,` it will work and show the sizes.

While in Examples 2 & 3: If the views are constructed outside of `Dimensions,` it will not work.

QUESTION: How would it work when the views are constructed outside? Thanks.

Running on Xcode Version 12.5.1 (12E507) target iOS 14.5

[image]

**Here's the code:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            // Example 1
            Dimensions {
                HStack {
                    
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                        .padding()
                    
                    // HelloWorldVariable   // <===== THIS WILL BREAK IT
                    // HelloWorldView()     // <===== THIS WILL BREAK IT
                }
            }.background(Color.blue)
            
            // Example 2
            Dimensions {
                HStack {
                    HelloWorldVariable // <===== THIS DOES NOT WORK in the HStack
                }
            }.background(Color.green)
            
            // Example 3
            Dimensions {
                HStack {
                    HelloWorldView() // <===== THIS DOES NOT WORK in the HStack
                }
            }.background(Color.yellow)
        }
    }
    
    private var HelloWorldVariable: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }
}

// MARK:- HelloWorldView
struct HelloWorldView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }
}

// MARK:- Dimensions
struct Dimensions<Content: View>: View {
    
    private var content: () -> Content
    @State private var contentSize: CGSize = .zero
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            content()
                .background(ObserveViewDimensions())
            
            VStack {
                Text("contentWidth \(contentSize.width)")
                Text("contentHeight \(contentSize.height)")
            }
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(DimensionsKey.self, perform: { value in
            self.contentSize = value
        })
    }
}

// MARK:- ObserveViewDimensions
struct ObserveViewDimensions: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Color.clear.preference(key: DimensionsKey.self, value: geometry.size)
        }
    }
}

// MARK:- DimensionsKey
struct DimensionsKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
    
    typealias Value = CGSize
}

// MARK:- Preview
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, it turns out the Canvas (SwiftUI Previews) has that bug in Xcode Version 12.5.1 (12E507).

The original code works on an iPhone X running iOS 14.8

There is a workaround to make it work for the Canvas, by changing the PreferenceKey to hold an array as seen in the code below.

Inspired by:
https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/

[image]

Here's the new code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            // Example 1
            Dimensions {
                HStack {
                    
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                        .padding()
                    
                     HelloWorldVariable
                    
                     HelloWorldView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var HelloWorldVariable: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }
}

// MARK:- HelloWorldView
struct HelloWorldView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }
}

// MARK:- Dimensions
struct Dimensions<Content: View>: View {
    
    private var content: () -> Content
    @State private var contentSize: CGSize = .zero
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            content()
                .background(ObserveViewDimensions())
            
            VStack {
                Text("contentWidth \(contentSize.width)")
                Text("contentHeight \(contentSize.height)")
            }
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(DimensionsKey.self, perform: { value in
            // 4. Add this
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.contentSize = value.first?.size ?? .zero
            }
        })
    }
}

// MARK:- ObserveViewDimensions 3. // <== update this with the new data type
struct ObserveViewDimensions: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Color.clear.preference(key: DimensionsKey.self, value: [ViewSizeData(size: geometry.size)])
        }
    }
}

// MARK:- DimensionsKey 2. // <== update this with the new data type
struct DimensionsKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: [ViewSizeData] = []
    
    static func reduce(value: inout [ViewSizeData], nextValue: () -> [ViewSizeData]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
    
    typealias Value = [ViewSizeData] 
}

// MARK:- ViewSizeData 1 <==== Add This
struct ViewSizeData: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let size: CGSize
    
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}

// MARK:- Preview
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).